# How to check if an error code matches error_reporting

Tags: php, error-handling, configuration, error-reporting

Let's say I have `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL & ~E_STRICT` and an error of level `E_USER_NOTICE` (or any other level) is triggered.

How can I check if that `E_USER_NOTICE` matches or doesn't match the above `E_ALL & ~E_STRICT`?

To clarify, given the example above, **if** `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT)` equaled an array of `[E_ERROR, E_NOTICE, E_WARNING ...]`, how could I check if `E_NOTICE` was in that metaphorical array.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Why, he didn't just done that?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Sadly not, because I don't know where to begin - never had to do this before.

Comment: I may be mistaking the question here, but error messages are triggered upon... error events, so way to go testing it raising one. May be your question about *how to raise one* for testing?

Comment: @AlanMachado Sorry if it's not clear. I know how to raise errors and register handlers. Given the example above, **if** `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT)` equaled an array of `[E_ERROR, E_NOTICE, E_WARNING ...]`, how could I check if `E_NOTICE` was in that metaphorical array. Edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: I think your question is answered by the PHP Docs: "*// Report all errors except E_NOTICE `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);`*". That said, you know EVERY error will be reported, every single one, **except** the one you specified.

Comment: I know what the syntax means; I am asking if there is a way to write a function like `matches_error_reporting($code, $settings = ini_get('error_reporting)) {}`

Comment: Ah ok, I've got it now, though I still miss the point in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be an easy `AND` operation. Check the following:

```
$errorLevels = E_ERROR | E_NOTICE;
echo $errorLevels & E_NOTICE ? 'match' : 'mismatch';
```